# I get error :SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

my code is :

```
   SELECT  EFF_DATE, COUNT(EFF_DATE),name
FROM TBL_LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAIL 
WHERE is_standard = 0 and name ='ساير جريانات نقدي ورودي  و اشخاص حقوقي غيرمالي';
GROUP BY  EFF_DATE,name
HAVING COUNT(EFF_DATE) = 43;
```

but I get error
please help me

my error is :

> ```
> Error starting at line : 5 in command -
> ```

HAVING COUNT(EFF_DATE) = 43
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: A non-grouped column followed by HAVING clause **must** be aggregated in order to prevent having such an error message.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* that you want the following logic:

```sql
SELECT VALUE, EFF_DATE, COUNT(EFF_DATE)  
FROM TBL_LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAIL 
GROUP BY VALUE, EFF_DATE
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN is_standard = 0 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(EFF_DATE) = 43;
```

This assumes that you want to return value/effective date combinations which have at least one record with `is_standard = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your having clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT VALUE, EFF_DATE, COUNT(EFF_DATE)  
FROM TBL_LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAIL 
WHERE is_standard = 0
GROUP BY VALUE, EFF_DATE
HAVING COUNT(EFF_DATE) = 43;
```

Showing us the structure of your table could be a help.

Comment: please take a look my edit code ,I get new error

Comment: @faziii1990 just remove the first **`;`** for the edited case

Comment: As Barbaros Özhan said you must remove the semicolon from the third line.